# Split worksheet in multiple workbooks based on unique values in range

Tags: excel, vba

It's been asked before but I haven't found a solution for unique values, I'm trying to split a large worksheet into workbooks based on the unique supervisors of T column, which contains the one in charge (one to many relationship / multiple employees for a supervisor).

My code currently scans the T column and runs the second code block to store and paste the rows associated to this person, the problem is that the loops runs for each row, no matter if the supervisor repeats itself 1000+ times, meaning that for each supervisor the file it's created `n` times.

```
emp       sup
-------------------
john doe  jane q public 'specific file for this supervisor
clint     jane q public 'it should be in the same file as the prev record
jenny doe jonny cage 'in separate file
```

Here's my code based on multiple answers on SO:

```
Option Explicit
'Split resp data into separate columns based on the names defined in
'a RESP on the FIRST sheet.
Sub splitRespVP()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Range

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each p In Sheets(1).Range("T2:T2201")
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate

        WritePersonToWorkbook wb, p.Value

        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sdoRespVP_" & p.Value
        wb.Close
    Next p
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Second code loop, where the file it's recreated multiple times for each duplicated supervisor:

```
'Writes all the sales data rows belonging to a Person
'to the first sheet in the named respWB.
Sub WritePersonToWorkbook(ByVal respWB As Workbook, _
                          ByVal Person As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim personRows As Range     'Stores all of the rows found
    Dim firstRW As Range        'containing Person in column 1
    For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows
        If Person = rw.Cells(2, 20) Then
            If personRows Is Nothing Then
                Set personRows = rw
                'Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            Else
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw

    personRows.Copy respWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) ' ACA ESTÀ EL ERROR
    Set personRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm looking to avoid looping each row and work on unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Used a dictionary and using each unique value I iterate the code and so far it worked fast:

```
Option Explicit
'Split resp data into separate columns baed on the names defined in
'a RESP on the FIRST sheet.
Sub splitRespVP()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '''''''''''
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim d As Object, i As Long, lr As Long
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
      d.Item(Range("T" & i).Value) = 1
    Next i
    '''''''''''

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each key In d.Keys()
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate

        WritePersonToWorkbook wb, key 'd.Item

        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sdoRespVP_" & key
        wb.Close
    Next key
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

'Writes all the sales data rows belonging to a Person
'to the first sheet in the named respWB.
Sub WritePersonToWorkbook(ByVal respWB As Workbook, _
                          ByVal Person As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim personRows As Range     'Stores all of the rows found
    Dim firstRW As Range        'containing Person in column 1
    For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows
        If Person = rw.Cells(2, 20) Then
            If personRows Is Nothing Then
                Set personRows = rw
                'Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            Else
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw

    personRows.Copy respWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) ' ACA ESTÀ EL ERROR
    Set personRows = Nothing
End Sub
```